# Flipview Items kept in memory

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have noticed that the FlipView control will keep 3 of its Items in memory at one time. It keeps in memory the item that is currently selected, as well as the Item directly to the left and to the right of the selected item (or above/below if orientation is vertical).

This has some unwanted side-effects when jumping to different flipview items. And they are especially noticeable on a Surface RT device (because it's so slow).

**Is there some way to keep all the flipview items in memory so that they are not loaded and unloaded as you swipe through it?**

**Or maybe a way to cache the flipview items as they are loaded?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent virtualisation you could replace the VirtualizeStackPanel in the ItemPanelTemplate by a StackPanel:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <StackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

But then you have to be careful of the tradeoff since it will load all the items on the first navigation and keep them in memory until you navigate away. 
Maybe a better approach would be more to look at what take the most time to load and try to optimise that (like if it load image or make some data processing at load time).

Comment: Oh my goodness! Of all the things I've tried and Googled, I can't believe I hadn't tried this. It works perfectly. I  completely understand what you're saying about the trade-off and I did consider that. In my case, I know I will have no more than 5 FlipView items which are pretty light (not many UIElements being drawn or long-running tasks associated).

Comment: Actually, combining this approach with binding the ItemsSource to an underlying collection that implements **ISupportIncrementalLoading** would be a nice solution for when you don't mind the memory footprint but just don't want the time cost associated with loading all of the UIElements all at once. Thanks again!